# What is the purpose of the reserved/undefined bit in the flag register?

Tags: cpu-architecture, x86-16, z80, 8085, intel-8080

In the flag register of Z80, 8080, 8085, and 8086 processors, what is the purpose of bits 1, 3, 5, which are documented as "reserved" or "undefined"?

Comment: Bit 1 on the Z-80 is defined as the N flag which indicates whether the last instruction was an add or subtract and is used by the DAA instruction.

Answer (score 10):

These bits are unused; that is, no instruction explicitly sets them to any value. The designers decided that 5/6 flags was enough, and they just left the remaining bits of the flags register unused.

They are documented as being "undefined" because it is not possible to know in advance which value will they have after any of the instructions are executed—the processor design is simpler that way, as opposed to setting them explicitly to 0 or 1.

Now, strictly speaking, and for the Z80 at least, these flags *do* actually get a predictable value—after all, a processor will always produce the same output and change to internal state given the same combination of input and previous internal state. For example, [this document about undocumented Z80 instructions](http://www.z80.info/z80undoc3.txt) says the following about CPI:

> Flag 3 and 5 are set like this: Take A, subtract the last (HL), and
>   then decrease it with 1 if the H flag was set (/after/ the CP). Bit 1
>   of this value is flag 5, bit 3 is flag 3.

The point, however, is that this behavior is *unintentional*—just a side effect—and not guaranteed to be present in future iterations of the processors. That's why they are documented as being just "undefined", as in, "they aren't useful to you so just ignore them".

Note that while on Z80 all bits of the `F` register can be set to any state, on i8080 bits 3 and 5 (that correspond to the undocumented Z80 flags) always read to be zero and bit 1 (that corresponds to Z80's N flag) always reads to be one.

Comment: "POP AF" on the Z-80 sets all the bits of the flag register so while there are no instructions that set undefined bits of the flag register via side effects there is one which will set all the bits.  Programs can and do safely assume that "POP AF; PUSH AF" will leave the top of the stack unchanged.

Comment: @GeorgePhillips:  ... if interrupts are disabled so that memory that's temporarily below the current stack pointer can't be asynchronously clobbered by an interrupt handler.

Comment: Well, yes, but a bit beside the point.  Let's say this, then.  PUSH HL, POP AF, PUSH AF, POP HL will not change the contents of HL.

Comment: for interest: a concise summary of 3/5 flags logic https://github.com/hoglet67/Z80Decoder/wiki/Undocumented-Flags